# Same URL, different response in .NET and browser

Tags: vb.net, get, webclient

When I use the URL, http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=cash-flow pasted directly into a browser window, I get the cash-flow data back and can do a view source to see the table of cash-flow values. However, when I use the same URL and do a GET in .NET it returns the base financials page (http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials) Below is the code I am using in .NET. This one is really stumping me and I’ve tried multiple methods to return the page in .NET and get the same response everytime. It appears to be ignoring the query string.

```
            Dim url As Uri = New Uri("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & stock("c_symbol") & "/financials?query=cash-flow")
            Dim str As String = Nothing
            isValid = True
            Using wb = New WebClient()
                Try
                    str = wb.DownloadString(url)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    isValid = False
                End Try
            End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "`DownloadString(Uri address)`" function is considering only base address but not query string.

So first set the query string to web client, then call "`DownloadString(Uri address)`"

```
Dim wb As New WebClient()
Dim myQueryStringCollection As New NameValueCollection()
myQueryStringCollection.Add("query","cash-flow");   
wb.QueryString = myQueryStringCollection;
str = wb.DownloadString(url)
```

**OR**

Call "`DownloadString(String)`" instead of "`DownloadString(Uri address)`"
For this do not declare URL as "`Uri`", instead declare URL as a "`string`"

```
Dim url As String
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these solves the issue. Still returns the base financials and not the cash-flow

Comment: could you please try with httpwebrequest/httpwebresponse. If 4.5 and above webrequest.

Comment: That was my original code using httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse. Same behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Can I just ask what the point is of having C# code in the first part when the OP's question is VB?

Comment: focused only on concept. will replace it or delete it if it wont work for him